# Angular Autocomplete is not working with dynamic data coming from API in JSON?

Tags: angular, autocomplete

Implementing Autocomplete on textbox in Angular data coming in JSON format but is it not working neither any error is showing in console only **showing empty array**. I am auto-completing with **Title field from API** through. I tried a lot but still not figure it out.
**API is Post method with JSON data structure below  I need Title to autocomplete**

```
 {
    Id: 1
    Title: "Zheng"
    WebSite: "www.tokyo.com"
    city: "Tokyo"
    }
```

**component.html**

```
<label class="label" for="company">Publication</label>
<input matInput placeholder="" class="input-text js-input" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="searchPublicationCtrl">
 <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
<mat-option *ngFor="let publication of  filteredPublication" [value]="publication.Title">
<mat-option *ngIf="isLoading" class="is-loading">Loading...</mat-option>
<span>{{publication.Title}}</span>
</mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AppServiceService } from './../app-service.service';
import { Subscriber } from 'rxjs';
import { FormControl,FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { debounceTime, tap, switchMap, finalize, startWith,  map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Subscription,of } from 'rxjs';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  searchPublicationCtrl = new FormControl();
  filteredPublication: any;
  isLoading = false;
  errorMsg: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,private auth : AppServiceService, private _router: Router, private formBuilder: FormBuilder,) {  }

  filteredStates: Subscription;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.auth.getPublication().subscribe(
      data => {
      console.warn(data);
    },
    error =>{
      console.log("Publication Error",error);

    }
    )
    this.searchPublicationCtrl.valueChanges
    .pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      tap(() => {
        this.errorMsg = "";
        this.filteredPublication = [];
        this.isLoading = true;
      }),
  
      switchMap(value => 
        this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/articles/publicationData",{} + value)
        .pipe(
          finalize(() => {
            this.isLoading = false
          }),
        )
      )
    )
    .subscribe(data => {
      if (data['Search'] == undefined) {
        this.errorMsg = data['Error'];
        this.filteredPublication = [];
      } else {
        this.errorMsg = "";
        this.filteredPublication = data['Search'];
      }

      console.log(this.filteredPublication);
    }); 


    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
  });



  }
  

}
```

**service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppSetting } from './appsetting'
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppServiceService {
  private SERVERURL = AppSetting.API;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(user){
    return this.http.post<any>(this.SERVERURL+"users",user);
  }

  getPublication(){
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let url  = ("http://localhost:3000/articles/publicationData");
    return this.http.post(url, { headers });
  }


}
```

Comment: Check this link 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wazyiq-xywdng?file=app/autocomplete-simple-example.ts

Comment: @RambabuPadimi but it says `filter` is not a function